# Oracle JDBC and Oracle CHAR data type

Tags: oracle, jdbc, types, char, prepared-statement

I have a tricky issue with the Oracle JDBC driver's handling of `CHAR` data types. Let's take this simple table:

```sql
create table x (c char(4));
insert into x (c) values ('a');  -- inserts 'a   '
```

So when I insert something into `CHAR(4)`, the string is always filled with whitespace. This is also done when I execute queries like this:

```sql
select * from x where c = 'a';    -- selects 1 record
select * from x where c = 'a ';   -- selects 1 record
select * from x where c = 'a   '; -- selects 1 record
```

Here, the constant `'a'` is filled with whitespace as well. That's why the record is always returned. This holds true when these queries are executed using a JDBC `PreparedStatement` as well. Now the tricky thing is when I want to use a bind variable:

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = 
  conn.prepareStatement("select * from x where c = ?");
stmt.setString(1, "a");    // This won't return any records
stmt.setString(1, "a   "); // This will return a record
stmt.executeQuery();
```

This is a workaround:

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = 
  conn.prepareStatement("select * from x where trim(c) = trim(?)");
stmt.setString(1, "a");    // This will return a record
stmt.setString(1, "a   "); // This will return a record
stmt.executeQuery();
```

**EDIT**: Now these are the constraints:

- The above workaround is not desireable as it modifies both the contents of `c` and `?`, AND it makes using indexes on `c` quite hard.
- Moving the column from `CHAR` to `VARCHAR` (which it should be, of course) is not possible

**EDIT**: The reasons for these constraints is because I ask this question from the point of view of the developer of [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org), a database abstraction library. So my requirements are to provide a very generic solution that doesn't break anything in jOOQ's client code. That is why I'm not really a big fan of the workaround. And that's why I don't have access to that `CHAR` column's declaration. But still, I want to be able to handle this case.

What would you do instead? What's a good practice for handling `CHAR` data types when I want to ignore trailing whitespace?

Comment: Even though you state that changing to VARCHAR is not an option (why?), VARCHAR is the only sensible solution to your requirement.

Comment: I agree with you. I'll explain in my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want

```
stmt.setString(1, "a");    // This won't return any records
```

to return a record, try

```
conn.prepareStatement("select * from x where c = cast(? as char(4))")
```

Comment: PS. I hate CHAR as a datatype.

Comment: I hate them as well. They look like being somewhat able to provide variable-length-functionality, but there are always pitfalls.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of casting the rhs to `CHAR(4)`. On the other hand, I'd need to know the exact length of the column (the problem is that `X` and `C` in my example are arbitrary placeholders...

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to use CHAR datatype even if it is char(1) in Oracle. Can you change the datatype instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option as it's not my database. My logic is just database abstraction... I will update the question accordingly

Comment: `CHAR` can be somewhat useful for codes, like ISO country/language/currency codes, etc. But I agree with you, as even then, it doesn't matter much. You could use `VARCHAR` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Gary's solution works well. Here's an alternative.

If you are using an Oracle JDBC driver, the call to `prepareStatement()` will actually return an `OraclePreparedStatement`, which has a `setFixedCHAR()` method that automatically pads your inputs with whitespace.

```
String sql = "select * from x where c = ?";
OraclePreparedStatement stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setFixedCHAR(1, "a");
...
```

Obviously, the cast is only safe if you are using the Oracle driver.

The only reason I would suggest that you use this over Gary's answer is that you can change your column sizes without having to modify your JDBC code. The driver pads the correct number of spaces without the developer needing to know/manage the column size.

Answer (score 0):

I have nice fix for this. You have to add one property while getting connection from database.

```
NLS_LANG=american_america.AL32UTF8
```

or in Java connection you can use below code:

```
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put ("user", user);
info.put ("password",password);
info.put("fixedString","TRUE");
info.put("NLS_LANG","american_america.AL32UTF8");
info.put("SetBigStringTryClob","TRUE");
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+serverName;
log.debug("url="+url);
log.debug("info="+info);
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,info);
```

Answer (score 0):

the other way is modify your sql as

```
select * from x where NVL(TRIM(c),' ') = NVL(TRIM('a'),' ')
```

Comment: Hi @張僑文 and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not quite a complete answer. Consider explaining WHY you could write the SQL in this manner, and WHY it would be beneficial to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add RTRIM() to the column name(which is defimed) in the update query.