# Java sql char prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, char, prepared-statement

I have a problem with a prepared statements with a `char(3)` parameter.

When I put the string directly into the SQL string I have no problem and the result set is correct, here's an example:

```
WHERE REQ.SERVICEID = 'SIN'
```

However, when I try to use a prepared statement in a safer way, I obtain no data!

The code is below:

```
" WHERE REQ.SERVICEID = ? "
```

and then

```
statement.setString(1,"SIN");
```

What is the problem?

Comment: If this is Oracle, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type

Comment: Thanks, it is an oracle database

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using utf-8, i.e. with mysql:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

For other databases, there should be analog options.