# Is setFixedCHAR() implemented in JOOQ

Tags: jooq

Our oracle database can't be changed and has lots of cols represented as CHARS.  Currently I am manually padding out parameters to the length of the field when making comparisons e.g. given foo is char(5) in the db 'foo  '

```
    String foo = "foo"

...    
        .where(FOO_TABLE.FOO.equal(StringUtils.rightPad(foo,FOO_TABLE.FOO.getDataType().length()))
```

is there any way that I can tell jooq that foo is a char thus it perform a padded comparison such as in rusty the robots answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786351/6065237)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [data type binding](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) for all `CHAR` columns and either cast the bind variable in the generated SQL string:

```
@Override
public final void sql(BindingSQLContext<String> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.render().sql("CAST(? AS CHAR(5))");
}
```

(I've just noticed that there is no way of getting access to the `CHAR` length this way..., this should be fixed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5223)

Or shorten / pad the bind variable prior to binding it to the prepared statement. Or you could [use that logic you referenced to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type/33786351#33786351) directly in your variable binding logic of your data type binding.

```
@Override
public final void set(BindingSetStatementContext<String> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.statement()
       .unwrap(OraclePreparedStatement.class)
       .setFixedChar(ctx.index(), ctx.value());
}
```

Any of these approaches would allow you to implement this logic only once.