# Issue with prepared statement when using select query with string

Tags: java, jdbc

I have written a simple JDBC program to do a query and trying to create the prepared statement, but the result set is coming as empty. But when the same query executed through general statement creation gives the output and also through SQL plus.

```
package com.aexp.balu.jdbc;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.*;

public class SimpleConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // String url="URL";
        // String uname="uname";
        // String pass="password";
        String url = "URL";
        String uname = "uname";
        String pass = "password";
        String query = "select CARD_NO from MDC.CAS_UNMCH_ROCS where CARD_NO = ?";
        String cardNumber = "3222222222222222223";

        try {

            // step1 load the driver class
            System.out.println("registering the driver");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            // step2 create the connection object . We need to have the type of
            // connection
            // The DriverManager class has a method get connection which give
            // sthe instance of Connection

            System.out.println("creating the connection....");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);

            // step3 create the statement object
            System.out.println("creating the statement");

            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            stmt.setString(1, cardNumber);

            // step4 execute query -- the stmnt object of the method execute
            // query results an object
            // of result set
            System.out.println("Executing the query");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("After Executing the query");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(" in reading result set");

                String cardnumber = rs.getString("CARD_NO");

                System.out.println(cardNumber);

            }
            // step5 close the connection object
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
registering the driver
creating the connection....
creating the statement
Executing the query
After Executing the query
```

Comment: try         String query = "from MDC.CAS_UNMCH_ROCS where CARD_NO = ?";

Comment: What's the type and size of the `CARD_NO` column?

Comment: tried it , the result is the same. The same query when executed through general statement that is by passing varaible value directly it gives me the output. So I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: Do you mean "Prepared statement"?

Comment: The definition of the same in the table is CARD_NO            NOT NULL CHAR(19)

Comment: Does a `select CARD_NO from MDC.CAS_UNMCH_ROCS` work?

Comment: Note that because the data type of the `CARD_NO` column is `CHAR` and not `VARCHAR`, the card number you pass in needs to be _exactly_ 19 characters long for the query to work (which seems to be the case in your example code, unless you changed the number).

Comment: Please show us also the code that works ("executed through general statement creation").

Comment: Thanks it worked, I had to pass the extra 4 spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle JDBC and Oracle CHAR data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type)