# Spring JdbcTemplate.update() is not updating the rows

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-2.5

I am using Spring `JdbcDaoSupport` in my DAO and trying to update the records using the following query.

```
String callersUpdateQuery = "update W67U999S a set pcrdattim= ? where exists (select b.CRDATTIM, b.RECORDCD, b.CRNODE, b.UNITCD, b.WRKTYPE from W03U999S b where a.PCRDATTIM = ? and a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE and a.PRECORDCD = 'F' and a.PCRNODE = '01' and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER' and b.UNITCD=? and a.crecordcd='T')";
```

The following is the code that should update the table:

```
 int updatedRowsCount =getJdbcTemplate().update(callersUpdateQuery, new Object[]{newFolderCrdattim, crdattim, businessAreaName});
```

But  getJdbcTemplate().update() is not updating the required rows and returning the updated rows count as zero. Weirdly, the same sql query when I execute at the database end, the records are getting updated. Can anyone guess what's wrong with the code or query?

The log messages are also showing correct values, but somehow the query is not updating the database:

```
21:04:01,288 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute] Executing prepared SQL statement [update W67U999S a set pcrdattim= ? where exists (select b.CRDATTIM, b.RECORDCD, b.CRNODE, b.UNITCD, b.WRKTYPE from W03U999S b where a.PCRDATTIM = ? and a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE and a.PRECORDCD = 'F' and a.PCRNODE = '01' and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER' and b.UNITCD=? and a.crecordcd='T')]
21:04:01,288 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
21:04:01,288 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver] Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.193.244.225:1521:AWD]
21:04:03,865 TRACE [org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal] Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [2017-08-09-10.33.10.168480], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
21:04:03,865 TRACE [org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal] Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [2017-07-20-04.22.20.893340], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
21:04:03,865 TRACE [org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal] Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [CS2XAA], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
21:04:04,115 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInPreparedStatement] SQL update affected 0 rows
21:04:04,131 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Comment: This could be because of the input parameters passed in the query at runtime. If possible check in your logs the final query formed before it is execute by JDBCTemplate

Comment: I have inspected the input parameters and insured they are fine

Comment: Did you tried to fetch from logs if you could get the final posted query to template.

Comment: Could be type cast is incorrect. e.g. you pass String for date or string for number.

Comment: maybe you need to make the method @Transactional(readonly=false) ?

Comment: @mhasan, The log messages are fine and not showing any clue. added log info to the question. Any clue now?

Comment: @ jpganz18, no use of `@Transactional(readonly=false) ` even. Any clue?

Comment: whats the data type for "pcrdattim" in db?

Comment: It's `Char`. `PCRDATTIM   NOT NULL CHAR(26) `.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle database

Comment: Ok, if it were MySQL, you could rewrite the same query differently. Have you tried to run it with hard coded values instead of the parameterized ?, to see if it is a casting issue as suggested in previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle `CHAR` type is the culprit here. The columns that I want to update are of type `CHAR`. That's causing the issue. This link helped me in figuring out the solution:
[Oracle JDBC and Oracle CHAR data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type)