# JDBC - PreparedStatement executeUpdate() returning 0

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
try{
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    String strUpdateQuery = "update payment_table set  CREDIT_CARD_NO = ? where PAYMENT_KEY= ?";
    PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(strUpdateQuery);
    for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++){
                ps.setString(1,"524364OQNBQQ4291");
                ps.setString(2,"20130215123757533280168");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
    }
}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not updating even a single row even after I checked the primary key is correct.

Comment: are you missing a beginTransaction ?

Comment: Also, why the loop?

Comment: What are you trying to convey with your title? It seems to be unrelated to your actual question.

Comment: Please show the code of `getConnection`, your DDL and sample data to reproduce this. Also specify the database you are using.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Transactions are implicitly started in JDBC when necessary (eg when executing a statement and no transaction is active), and given he is calling `commit()`, we can assume auto-commit is disabled (otherwise calling commit should throw an exception)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - I am using a product which gives me the connection, I havent coded to get the connection. I am using Oracle db 11.2 .

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - Yes I have disabled the auto-commit. And my question is why the rows are not getting updated using prepared statement after I set the string and do executeupdate. No error what so ever.

Comment: Maybe my hint wasn't clear enough: edit the title so it actually covers the question (for example what does "setString() is void" have to do with your problem?!). And include your code from `getConnection()`, the DDL of your table, and a sample population of your data. You need to provide us with sufficient information to diagnose your problem. Apart from your curious loop that doesn't do anything (except attempt to re-execute **the same** update over and over again), there is no obvious error in your code.

Comment: Below link answer's the question I posted : [Oracle JDBC and Oracle CHAR data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

Try with batch update:

```
void batchUpdate() {
    String strUpdateQuery = "UPDATE payment_table " +
                            "SET CREDIT_CARD_NO = ? " +
                            "WHERE PAYMENT_KEY= ?";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strUpdateQuery)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            ps.setString(1, "524364OQNBQQ4291");
            ps.setString(2, "20130215123757533280168");
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        int[] updated = ps.executeBatch();
        // can log updated rows from "updated"
        // conn.commit(); in case autocommit set to false or used conn.setAutoCommit(false) somewhere
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with batch update too. But no error also, no luck. Yes I and  using conn.setAutoCommit(false) in my code.

Comment: This suggestion is not really relevant to the problem described.

Answer (score -1):

`ps.setXxx()`: You can check the order. The sequence must be the same as the column names in the result level returned by the resultSet!!